# Ruby on Rails installation - An error occurred while installing nio4r

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install ROR and starting a first application. 
I installed it via RailsInstaller.

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
```

I'm using windows 10 64 bits. Actually, the ruby version is 32 bits since I installed it via RailsIntaller (I did not find a 64 bits package on their website)

However, when executing bundle install, the cmd displays the following:

```
current directory:
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe -r
./siteconf20170821-16180-18y9lyl.rb extconf.rb --with-cflags=-std=c99
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory --
extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The log file contains the following:

```
current directory: C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio‌​4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170821-16180-18y9lyl.rb extconf.rb --with-cflags=-std=c99 C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError) extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Please note that I tried multiple ways to install ROR (railsIntaller, rubyInstaller+devKit 32/64 bit versions ...) but the error above is the same each time. I also checked environment variables and I confirm that user and system variables point to ruby.exe

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What's in the log file it says it logged the output to?

Comment: it shows:
current directory: C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170821-16180-18y9lyl.rb extconf.rb --with-cflags=-std=c99
C:/dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: Please add the error to the post (instead of smushing it into a comment).